# It is possible to set icon (in .sed file), working with IExpress?

Tags: windows-installer, ico, iexpress

I want to create an .exe from my .msi.

I use for it (with good result):

```
IExpress /N myFile.SED
```

*myFile.SED* was generated by *Start menu->Run->IExpress*. I want to change the icon (.ico) for the final .exe with IExpress.

I know that I can change .ico for .exe in other programs, even in Visual Studio, but I want to do it at once.

**Does IExpress supports setting icons for .exe generated from .msi?**

If so, how to set it to *myIcon.ico*? I couldn't find any apropiate line in *myFile.SED*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use IExpress to create setup.exe's anymore.  There were several security vulnerabilities found in it and Microsoft has since abandoned it.

Instead take a look at the Burn bootstrapper in Windows Installer XML.  It's a much more robust solution for creating a bootstrapper/chainer for your MSI.

In Burn you use the Bundle@IconSourceFile attribute to brand the EXE and Add/Remove Programs entry.

Comment: I see, but I do have icon in Add/Remove Programs, I just need and .ico for .exe installer. Still it's good point to migrate from IExpress. I will mark that answer as right one, even if it does not explain if IExpress has or has not ability to set .ico for .exe installer.